# Rails Controllers - Adding a Custom Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I have an Article resource and have defined resourceful routes for it. I want to create a simple page that shows the articles of the current user. I am aware that it is possible to do so by adding another action, for example 'search' to articles controller which will contain the custom code that searches for articles that have the same user id. And for the routes:

```
resources :articles do
  get 'search'
end
```

But I'm not sure if adding a custom action is a good idea in this case. I'm thinking I can still use the index action (which shows all articles) and pass some sort of parameter from the url so that it can distinguish if the user wants to see all articles or just his own. But I'm not sure exactly how this can be done. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query string to pass parameters. see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string)
So you can pass something like `.../articles?user_id=2`
In your controller, just change the behavior according to the user_id parameter.

Comment: BTW. You can also do something similar by using nested resource routes, and add a nested articles resource under the user resource, but it may be a bit of an overkill here.

Comment: Great, just what I needed. I'll pass it on the link_to method and modify the index action of the controller. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to create a new action/view for it.

You can add a small form to filter `all articles` or only `my articles`, for example:

```
<%= form_tag articles_path, method: :get do %> 
    <%= radio_button_tag :search, "all", :checked => true %>
    <%= label_tag :all %><br />

    <%= radio_button_tag :search, "my" %>
    <%= label_tag :my_articles %><br />

    <%= submit_tag "filter", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

than in your controller:

```
def index
  if params[:search] == 'my'
    @articles = current_user.articles
  else
    @articles = Article.all
end
```

Comment: hmm..I don't really need a filter right now. Basically, I just want a link to the page, so I was thinking if a parameter could be passed in the url.